# Сбой подключения c Microsoft Exchange 2013

Tags: windows, сеть, outlook, exchange

В локальной сети есть почтовый сервер Microsoft Exchange 2013, Домен контроллер 2012 и соответственно ПК юзеров на винде.

Иногда пропадает подключение в клиенте MS Outlook с сервером Microsoft Exchange. Решается вопрос передергиванием сетевого интернет кабеля (либо вкл. выкл. подключения на ПК). Происходит это рендомно.

С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: А остальная сеть пашет?

Comment: да, мне подсказали в логах посмотреть самого Outlook. Включил лог, буду наблюдать

Comment: Как знакомо!!!! У нас та же самая песня. Причём, что интересно, если юзер использует пароль на ТМ или совместный, то происходит вывод окна ввода пароля, а если пароль клавиатурный, то при разрыве соединения восстанавливается само (пароль не сохранен). Происходит как на Office2010, так и на Office2016. Есть подозрение, что трабл скрывается в самом Exchange. Однако, почтари не колятся, а у меня доступа к логам сервера нет. Это происходит у всех пользователей по нескольку раз на дню. Парк >50000. Не имею информации, к сож., что по этому поводу говорит поддержка мелкомягких